# Why wouldn't my ajax run? No errors being thrown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the `id`of the button when its clicked process it through AJAX like shown in index.php and just echoing it out simply.

Howevr when I do that PHP tells me that `postid is an undefined index`. What's the problem here please?

As I am new to AJAX I am following this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVAaxkbmCts).

Index.php:

```
<button type='submit' id=8 onclick='addToCart(this.id)'></button>
```

```js
function addToCart($id) {
  var idStored = $id; //When the button is clicked it passes the id. Even .val() wouldn't work
  $.post('../Cart.phtml',{postid:idStored}, function(data){
    window.alert(data); //Just for testing and conforming the code runs.
  });
}
```

CartPage.php:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['postid'];
  echo $name;
?>
```

Many thanks, any help or guidance would be great.

Comment: `addToMyWishList` != `addToCart` Other things it could be: 1. Any function called from an old-fashioned `onxyz`-attribute handler has to be a global. Perhaps your function isn't global. 2. That button is a **submit** button. Normally, submitting a form refreshes the page, which will prevent the ajax call from completing (or, likely, even starting).

Comment: Sorry yes, my mistake I forgot to change that too. But still nothing. Is my syntax at least correct?

Comment: If your button is within a `form` then it's most likely that the form is being submit before the AJAX request is sent/completed and so gets aborted.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, sorry so how can I make my function global? Also, should I just remove the type = submit so the page doesn't refresh?

Comment: You'd need to set `type="button"` to stop the refresh for testing purposes, but I wouldn't do that in production. Hook to the `submit` event of the `form` using an unobtrusive handler instead of the `on*` event attribute. Then you can cancel the event using `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I don't have a form attached to the button

Comment: In which case check the console to see exactly what the content of your AJAX request is

Answer (score 0):

First send `event` object to the method like below:

```
<button type='submit' data-id="8" onclick='addToCart(event, this.id)'></button>
```

`$.post` send a ajax request with content-type `application/json` and the request object is **NOT** in `form-data` format and that is in `request payload` format.

```
function addToCart(e, $id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var idStored = $id; //When the button is clicked it passes the id. Even .val() wouldn't work
  $.post('../Cart.phtml',{postid:idStored}, function(data){
    window.alert(data); //Just for testing and conforming the code runs.
  });
}
```

To read `request payload` in `PHP` do as below:

CartPage.php:

```
<?php
  // read request payload json data    
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  $name = $data ['postid'];
  echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the constructive reply. When I do json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) inside the file get contents parameter. Am I suppose to leave it the same or change the directory location to were the function 'addToCart' is running. Because when I ran this and click on the button then click on the cart page, it's an empty page

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, can you describe better? // if my answer helped you please don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: In your solution you told me to put this code in cartpage.php: <?php
  // read request payload json data    
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  $name = $data ['postid'];
  echo $name;
?>. Where you have  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); for the fileGetContents, should I change the parameter to point to index.php. Like so: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('index.php'));. Because when I run your code and click on cart page nothing is outputted. I thought it was filegetcontents

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using onClick() function.

```
//using form and type=”submit” is not needed
<button id=8 onclick='addToCart(this.id)'></button>
```

But if you want to do it through form, you have to prevent the default behavior of the form.

```
$("#cartForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed my button options to that. And when I click on the button an alert saying "<?php
$name = $_POST['postid'];
echo $name;
?>" comes up. When I clicked on the cart page it fails to recognize postid

Comment: Try using $.ajax() method instead of $.post()

study this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600596/get-the-return-value-of-a-html-form-post-method